# How to make command ping to output with domain name which I ping?

Tags: linux, ping

E.g., I type `ping www.domain.com` and the output I want is like:

```
64 bytes from yyy.xxx.com (www.domain.com): icmp_seq=32 ttl=52 time=84.8 ms
```

(or other format with domain name).

Comment: OK ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible by any flag ping command provides.
But we always can roll up our sleeves and get hands dirty.

```
ping google.com | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*\+\:\)/\1 (google.com)/g'
```

Considering output format includes something like that "64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.397 ms"  we can try to parse with sed.
So, sed looks for digit and ":" symbol afterwards, replaces it to "digit: (google.com)".